# mysql json where in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have two tables like the below. But I got a trouble on querying.
I want to query all the post which the member in the group is equal to the can_view_group, and the can_view_group column type is JSON.

I only know JSON_CONTAINS and WHERE (column) IN may help me get the job done, but I cant actually get it work. How can I get it work?

Thanks.

P.S. I just want the plain SQL code since it should be the most simple when I apply it to the php code or any other things.

```
                post
----------------------------------------
     post_id    |    can_view_group    |
----------------------------------------
        1       |   ["1","2","3"]      |
----------------------------------------

              member_group
----------------------------------------
    member_id   |       group_id       |
----------------------------------------
      123       |           1          |
----------------------------------------
      123       |           2          |
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Better normalize your data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple is to use multiple nested `REPLACE` functions to get a comma separated string and MySQL's denormalized function `FIND_IN_SET` which works with a comma separated string.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 post 
INNER JOIN
 member_group
ON
 FIND_IN_SET(member_group.group_id , REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(post.can_view_group, '"', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''))
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37e997/5

**One downside you are never be able to use a index with this approach.**

Best option still is to normalize but that would require a application change for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed! It is just amazing. How would be the structure if i want to normalize it for this situation?